# how do I run my .py file from within python command line?

Tags: windows

background info:
I know this question has been asked countless times, but I'm not understanding the answers.
Today is the first time I've ever done anything with python, so I'm a total noob.
I'm using windows 7.
python 3.3.5 lives here: C:\Python33\python.exe
I have a .py file I want to run saved here: C:\Users\Scydmarc\Documents\cs188\python_basics\myfile.py

If I simply double click on myfile.py, it opens, runs, and closes super fast. By doing a perfectly timed printscreen, I can see that it works. It is my understanding that I need to run the file from within python.exe to get the window to stay open and allow me to mess with variables etc after it runs. So I open python.exe. What exactly do I need to type to run myfile.py? I've found lots of people trying to do this, but I guess I'm not understanding the answers. When I try to follow along, I get tangled up with errors. Do you still need to put python before the file name while in the python.exe window? Do I somehow need to specify a full path to the file? Some are actually running from the windows command prompt and not the python command prompt. When trying to change PYTHONPATH, are you supposed to do that from inside python, or the windows command prompt? Some examples use '/', while some use '\'. So, I think a complete example (what to actually type, in what window, line by line, with real filepaths) would clarify a lot for me and be super helpful. I'm thinking if I can actually see it done once, I can figure out how to make it do what I want in the future. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: can somebody share how to run a script from the PYTHON command line? Not the windows command line. I want to be able to mess with the variables when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

in your python dir type python.exe pathtofile.py or set python.exe to your classpath

edit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IokKz-LZsEo

Comment: I do not know what you mean by this. What window do I type that into? How do I get whatever window I'm using to the python dir? How do I set a classpath?

Comment: 1. open your commandline eg. cmd.exe
2. go in your phyton dir eq. C:\Python27
3. type python.exe pathToDir.py
4. have fun http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/a3c97d-1394938632.jpg

Comment: following your instructions, I can run myfile.py from the windows cmd.exe, but since I'm not in the actual python window, once it's done I can't do anything with it. I would like to run it from inside the python command line so afterwards I can still access the variables and stuff like that.
http://postimg.org/image/iw0i64udf/